# GraphQL Code Generator not generating code in Next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, next.js, react-apollo

I've got a `codegen.yml` that looks as follows:

```yaml
overwrite: true
schema: http://localhost:3001/graphql
documents: "./src/graphql/**/*.graphql"
generates:
./src/generated/graphql.tsx:
  plugins:
    - typescript
    - typescript-operations
    - typescript-react-apollo
  config:
    withHooks: true
```

I have a  script in the package.json that looks as follows:

```json
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "generate": "graphql-codegen"
  }
```

This is my folder structure:

```
- root
     - package.json
     - codegen.yml
     - src
         - generated
         - graphql
            - mutations
               - login.grahql
            - queries
```

The `login.grahql` looks as follows:

```
query{
  user{
    username
    createdAt
    email
    id
    isLoggedIn
    fullName
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

When I run

```sh
$ yarn generate
```

I get

```sh
yarn run v1.22.10
$ graphql-codegen
Done in 12.10s.
```

But I don't see any generated `code`. I was following [the docs](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo). What may be possibly my problem.

Comment: The indentation of `generates` looks weird. Have a look at https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/codegen-config for how it should look. Admittedly, it seems the [usage example in the docs you linked](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript-react-apollo) appears broken - you might consider filing a bug report.